# How do I replace all occurrences of text after a word and a space with a date variable that contains the next Saturday using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I have text in a file like this:

executes_at: "2025-02-23T01:00:00Z"

I need to replace all occurrences of this in the file with the next Saturday in the calendar. I've managed to store the date in the correct format, but can't get the regex right using sed to update this text.

I've got this for the date:

```
NEXTSATURDAY=$(date --date="next saturday" +"%Y/%m/%d")
RUN_DATE='"'${NEXTSATURDAY}'T01:00:00Z"'
echo $RUN_DATE
```

Then i'm trying to use sed with this variable to input it, replacing "2025-02-23T01:00:00Z"

I've got this for the sed command:

```
sed -i "\[.*^$-:/(executes_at: \)\[.*^$-:/\1$RUN_DATE/\" myFolder/file.yml
```

Would anyone be able to help with what the sed command would be, please?

Thanks

Comment: Why not `sed -i 's/executes_at:[ ]["][^"]*["]/executes_at: "'"$RUN_DATE"'"/' file` ?

Comment: The variable contains slashes which conflicts with the `s///` command delimiters, so simply use different delimiters: `s,pattern,replacement,` -- alternately use **bash** parameter expansion to escape the slashes: `sed "s/pattern/${RUN_DATE//\//\\\/}/"`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it, thanks David:

sed -i 's/executes_at:[ ]["][^"]*["]/executes_at: "'"$RUN_DATE"'"/' file